# EF Error: The entity type 'X' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, xunit.net

I am using dotnet core 6.0 and EF 6.0. I have the following entities:

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
    [Table("User", Schema = "cl")]
    public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key] 
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public int ExternalId { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Core.Database
{
    public class UserDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public UserDbContext(bool inherited, DbContextOptions options) : base(inherited, options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Upload> Upload { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UploadObject> UploadObject { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(UserDbContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a test using xUnit to test the database queries, so I am using InMemory Database. The test looks like this:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
    using Moq;
    using Xunit;

    public class UserServiceTests
    {
        private readonly UserService _userService;
        private readonly UserDbContext _userDbContext;
        
        public UserServiceTests()
        {
            // Setup Database
            var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase("UserServiceTest")
                .ConfigureWarnings(b => b.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
                .Options;
            _userDbContext = new UserDbContext(dbContextOptions);
            _userDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            _userDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            
            _userService = new UserService(_userDbContext);
        }
    }
```

When I run and debug the test (I know that at the moment I am not running any test, just the constructor) when in the constructor reaches this line:

```
_userDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

I get this error:

> The entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

However, my entity does have a primary key and if I run the project, I can see that in the database the primary key is there.
I have read about the different options like use the HasNoKey in the OnModelCreating method or using [Keyless] Data Annotation attribute, but none of them seem correct to me since the entity does have a primary key and it's there.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the imports of the file where you defined `class User`?

Comment: Where's the DbContext? How are you defining and configuring the entities? Shouldn't `BaseEntity` be an abstract class?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried that and also removing the BaseEntity but got the same error.

Comment: First of all @PanagiotisKanavos is right. `BaseEntity` should be abstract. Can you try `
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute on `Id` property. And try to regenerate migrations.

Comment: @bugrakosen thanks for your reply. This didn't do anything, still same issue.